# How can I get the ajax post with my flask app if I have more than one input

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, file-upload, flask

I was able to post a single file to my flask app, but when I tried to use more than one input in the ,my flask app couldn't get anything .

Below is my html code.

```
<head>
<title>Practice AJAX</title>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#upload-file-btn').click(function() {
        var form_data = new FormData($('#upload-file')[0]);
    //for each entry, add to formdata to later access via $_FILES["file" + i]
    /*    for (var i = 0, len = 2; i < len; i++) {
        form_data.append("file" + i, $('#file')[i]);
        }*/
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ajax',
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
              window.location = "/result"
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Flask AJAX Test</h1>
<form id="upload-file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
    <label for="mRNA">Select a file</label>
    <input name="mRNA" type="file" >
    <label for="lncRNA">Select a file</label>
    <input name="lncRNA" type="file" >
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <button id="upload-file-btn" type="button">Upload</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
```

And I have tried to use request.files.getlist to get my formdata list,but it seems like it didn't work at all.

```
@app.route('/ajax', methods=['POST'])
def ajax():

upload_file = request.files.getlist('upload-file')

for file in upload_file:
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
       filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
       file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], Case_ID + filename))
        # Save the filename into a list, we'll use it later
       filenames.append(filename)

return redirect('/result')
```

MY code will just redirect to /result and without saving the files in server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
@app.route('/ajax', methods=['POST'])
def ajax():
    # Create a list of all files (e.g. ['mRNA', 'lncRNA'])
    filelist = [name for name in request.files]

    # For every file in the filelist
    for f in filelist:
        # Get the particular file
        file = request.files[f]

        # Check whether the file is valid
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            # Create a secure filename
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            # Save file to UPLOAD_FOLDER
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], Case_ID + filename))

    # You don't have to redirect with Flask. jQuery redirects you if the AJAX call was successfull.
    return "success"
```